# swift print string interpolation and folder path

Tags: string, swift, interpolation

in swift how do I specify a local file's path using string interpolation.
When I do something like the following

```
let fileName = "myFile.jpg"
let fullPath = "folder/(fileName)"
```

I don't get a '/' at all between folder and the interpolated file name, and when I use '//' I get the '//' instead of the actual file name.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try it with backslash, but the methods to handle path components are preferable.

Comment: Do you mean `"folder\(fileName)"`?

Answer (score 2):

For simply printing folder/file path:

```
let fileName = "myFile.jpg"
let fullPath = "folder/\(fileName)"
print(fullPath)
/* Prints: folder/myFile.jpg */

let fileName = "myFile.jpg"
let fullPath = "folder\\\(fileName)"
print(fullPath)
/* Prints: folder\myFile.jpg */
```

Regarding string interpolation and escape characters in Swift, see [Swift Language Guide - Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html):

> **String interpolation**
>
> String interpolation is a way to construct a new String value from a
>   mix of constants, variables, literals, and expressions by including
>   their values inside a string literal. Each item that you insert into
>   the string literal is wrapped in a pair of parentheses, prefixed by a
>   backslash:
>
> ```
> let multiplier = 3
>
> let message = "\(multiplier) times 2.5 is \(Double(multiplier) * 2.5)"
> ```
>
> In the example above, the value of multiplier is inserted into a
>   string literal as `\(multiplier)`.
>
> ...
>
> **Special Characters in String Literals**
>
> String literals can include the following special characters:
>
> - The escaped special characters \0 (null character), `\\` (backslash), \t (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), \" (double
>     quote) and \' (single quote)
>
> ...

As vadian writes, however, methods to handle path components are preferable, see e.g.

- [Read and write data from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file)
- [Get image from documents directory swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005381/get-image-from-documents-directory-swift)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to produce path for Windows, because forward slash `/` does not interfere with string interpolation in any way.

The proper expression for `\` inside interpolated string in front of an interpolation expression you need three backslashes:

```
let fullPath = "folder\\\(fileName)"
```

- The first slash escapes the slash
- The second slash is the slash that gets into the interpolated string
- The third slash signals the beginning of an interpolation sequence `\(...)`

Answer (score 0):

more fun in a playground to show some API you might be interested in:

```
import Foundation

let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/foo/bar/")
let fileUrl = NSURL(string: "myfile.jpg", relativeToURL: url)
fileUrl?.absoluteString
fileUrl?.absoluteURL
fileUrl?.fileURL
fileUrl?.hasDirectoryPath
fileUrl?.pathComponents
```