# Load multiple image from directory using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, image

I am new to iOS `swift` programming really need help!

I downloaded images from url and saved to the path **/Users/mymac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/583C02D5-9A88-4756-9044-CD6DB4DCB57C/data/Containers/Data/Application/699F623B-000B-4365-B451-CA3104AD958B/Documents/Images**

Now i am able load images `ImageView` by specifying the name manually

```
    var fileName = "Images/1A_Dorsal aspect.jpg"
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    var getImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    imageLoad.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: getImagePath)
```

what i need is load the **image** using the number (i.e 25 images are in my folder Images) using for loop i want to load the images one by one like Android(Java)

Comment: This question is related to ios,

Comment: Yes using swift language in iOS

Answer (score 1):

**Load multiple images from the folder or directory. - Swift 4**

Here's the image attached to show, what we want to achieve in the given below code.
[image]

Here's the code to find the multiple images from the folder in documents directory. I have written one method to do the same.

> In the code we are passing the "Folder Name" (ie. Red) and getting the
>   contents of that directory. In return we got the array of images name.

```
static func loadImagesFromAlbum(folderName:String) -> [String]{

    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
    var theItems = [String]()
    if let dirPath          = paths.first
    {
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(folderName)

        do {
            theItems = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: imageURL.path)
            return theItems
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return theItems
        }
    }
    return theItems
}
```

Here's the result of given code. 
[image]

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you get all images name which store in "Images" folder Try bellow code:

```
 let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
 let arrImages : NSMutableArray = []
            let tempFolderPath = AppHelper.fileInDocumentsDirectory("Images")
            do {
                let filePaths = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(tempFolderPath)
                for filePath in filePaths {
                        try arrImages.addObject(tempFolderPath + "/" + filePath)

                }
            } catch {
                print("Could not get folder: \(error)")
            }
print(arrImages)
```

Comment: But how can i load images to imageView?

Comment: Are you using tableView ?

Comment: No i am using Imageview and pageItemController to scroll.Upon scrolling the pages i want the images to be changed

Comment: Just review this example :- https://github.com/UnicornTV/Swift-Example-UIPageViewController

Comment: exactly what you referred but what i need in this is to load images from directory folder (i.e inside device) .for ex 1.png,2.png,3.png...How can i do it??

Comment: Save image on document directory hear :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005381/get-image-from-documents-directory-swift