# swift: Load multiple files from documents directory

Tags: ios, swift

I have folder with many files in documents directory. In my folder I have files with different extensions (jpg, png, mp3, zip). In my code I have `stringArray`. I want to load all files in `someArray` and after that add files with `.png` extension from `someArray` in `stringArray` How to do it?

Is it possible to do this? Or I should find another way to load multiple files from documents directory?

I find [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49029772) for `Load multiple images from the folder or directory. - Swift 4`

I tried to use this code from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49029772):

```
func loadImagesFromAlbum(folderName:String) -> [String]{

        let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
        let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
        let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
        var theItems = [String]()
        if let dirPath          = paths.first
        {
            let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(folderName)

            do {
                theItems = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: imageURL.path)
                return theItems
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return theItems
            }
        }
        return theItems
    }
```

But I can't get files from `theItems`. Because `theItems` it a string array. What I do wrong? How to get files from `loadImagesFromAlbum`?

I tried to use this code:

```
images = loadImagesFromAlbum(folderName: "/folder1")
```

But it is not help me. I get only names. But I need to get files.

**Update**

I use this code to load image from `documents directory`:

```
        let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
        let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
        let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
        if let dirPath          = paths.first
        {
            let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("/folder1/1.png")
            myImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
        }
```

But I need to load 100 images from `/folder1` in `var images = [String]()`. Because I use `var images = [String]()` to show images: `contentVC.imageName = images[index] // and etc...`

And the code I use above is not very convenient if I need add 40-100 images.

**Update 1**

I have this code to load images from my project and show it:

```
class PageViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            for page in 1...pageNumber[indexPage] {
                images.append("page\(page).png")

            }
}

func getContentViewController(withIndex index: Int) -> ContentViewController? {
        if index < images.count{
            let contentVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController
            contentVC.itemIndex = index
            contentVC.imageName = images[index]

            return contentVC
        }

        return nil
    }
}

import UIKit

class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var itemIndex: Int = 0
    var imageName: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let currentImage = imageName{
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: currentImage)

        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

But I need to load images from documents directory and show it. How to do it?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You cannot load *files* into an array. You could load the **contents** of a file (its `Data` representation) into an array. `contentsOfDirectory` returns an array of string paths which are the locations of the files on disk.

Comment: @vadian I updated question. Add new code below **Update** title.

Comment: It's still unclear. You are talking about 3 different things: The file paths are `String`, the images are `UIImage`  – you cannot append an `UIImage` to a `String` array – but the name `imageName` implies that it expects only the file name (the last path component) of the file path.

Comment: @vadian I updated my question. And I asked new question below **Update 1** title. Please tell me if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to load an image for a specific name in a specific folder in the `Documents` folder.

Please try this, the method takes two parameters, the file name (with extension!) and the folder name and returns an `UIImage` or `nil` if the image cannot be found or created.

```
func loadImage(withName name : String, from folderName: String) -> UIImage? {
    do {
        let documentsFolderURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let imageURL = documentsFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(folderName).appendingPathComponent(name)
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
        return UIImage(data: data)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

There is no benefit to get all file paths with `contentsOfDirectory` because you have to load the image data one by one anyway.

Comment: Thank you! This code work fine. I use this code `let currentImage = loadImage(withName: imageName!, from: "/folder")` `imageView.image = currentImage` in contentViewController. Is it the right usage?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need the leading `/`. `appendingPathComponent` handles the path separators.