# iPhone 7 not displaying webview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, wkwebview

I am designing a webview app in ios. I started making change in my code. And the code change is perfectly alright. The app is responding in simulator(iPhone 7) as it should respond. But when I deploy the app to device(iPhone 7) the app only displays blank page.

It is weird. I read many articles where they were talking about network carrier. Currently it is showing `No Service`. I tried re-inserting the sim card. But it was of no use. I dont know if that was of any use or not.

If someone could tell what all should I try to debug this out.

> Question Update

How I am loading webview

Case 1: When I take the `index.html` from softlink in project directory then I am able to do it in my device

```
func getLandingPage() -> URLRequest {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "www", ofType: nil)!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(path)/index.html")
    return URLRequest(url: url)
}
```

URL created- `"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/9890F84F-4CF4-48AB-8874-AC1BC0B77C55/ios.app/www/index.html"`

case 2: When I copy all the files from my softlink directory to directory inside documentDirectory of device and then if I try to load `index.html` from there then it displaying blank page. And I want this to happen correctly.

```
func getLandingPage() -> URLRequest {
    let docURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let pathData = "\(docURL[0].path)/\(CODE_FOLDER)/index.html"
    let url     = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathData)

    return URLRequest(url: url)
}
```

URL create- `"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/427943C3-2238-49A3-AFCC-5561062B7CDA/Documents/CODE/index.html"`

Comment: Are you connected to internet or not?

Comment: make sure you can browse the internet on that device even it's a simulator or real device

Comment: I am connected to internet. And I can browse it too

Comment: Seems like your file is not fetched from the path. could you try to debug wheather the file exist at path. this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/29005938/2323806

Comment: Check you link path if its written correctly or try it from wi-fi connection and check if its works ?  Print your pathdata and check if its correctly printed or there is some mistake.

Comment: I have checked that. The folder is containing all the copied files. And the simulator is loading all those files.

Comment: there is a prefix file://.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check that URL through this if its opening or not on a button tap to debug weather its working fine or not in device in your condition.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "your url string/ path") // or directly your URL
            else { return }
 if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
 {
     if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
     } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
     }
 }
else
{
  print("This doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
}
```

**You can also try this out as documents directory on simulator is different from the real device:**

```
let documentDirUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)  // give your url here 
let indexFileUrl = documentDirUrl.appendingPathComponent("index.html") // then append the path component of your html file
webView.loadFileURL(indexFileUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: documentDirUrl)    // load the webview
```

Comment: I got this log "This app is not allowed to query for scheme file" for the first test. I am trying the second one

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala Right its because not registering the URL scheme in the info.plist file. That will not help i think URL schemes are used to check weather application will open external links or not . My mistake.

Comment: Second part solved my issue. Now can you please explain why it was happening?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala Its because Documents directory on simulator is different from the real device, it's as usual. That must be the reason .

Comment: Reason is satisfactory for now. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this one for local folders. You can check if your is File exit or not.

```
func getLandingPage() -> URLRequest {
let docURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let path = "\(CODE_FOLDER)/index.html"
let url = documentURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: (url?.path)!) {
return URLRequest(url: url)
} else {
 print("File doesn't exists")
}
}
```

Comment: it is showing the file exist but the webview is not loading

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala try to append the path component of your html file to directory url. For more info check my edited answer. Hope it helps!